# Set CRS of simple polygon

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I have a simple polygon:

`extent = sf::st_polygon(list(matrix(c(-88.17182, 40.06722, -88.17182, 43.06722, -85.17182, 43.06722, -85.17182, 40.06722, -88.17182, 40.06722), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)))`.

How can I set the CRS to EPSG:4326?

I thought certainly `sf::st_set_crs(extent, 'EPSG:4326')` or `sf::st_crs(extent) <- 4326` would work, but both fail with `no applicable method for 'st_crs<-' applied to an object of class "c('XY', 'POLYGON', 'sfg')"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `st_csr` call on each side. Although, you are missing a step `sf::st_sfc` in creating the correct object type.

```
e <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_polygon(list(matrix(c(-88.17182, 40.06722, 
                -88.17182, 43.06722, -85.17182, 43.06722, -85.17182, 
                40.06722, -88.17182, 40.06722), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))))

    sf::st_crs(e) <- sf::st_crs(4326)
```

The right side creates the projection object which is then piped into the spatial object. Although, with valid sfc geometry you can now now pass the crs directly.

```
e <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_polygon(list(matrix(c(-88.17182, 40.06722, 
                -88.17182, 43.06722, -85.17182, 43.06722, -85.17182, 
                40.06722, -88.17182, 40.06722), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))), 
                crs=4326)
```

Comment: I tried that as well, same error

Comment: @DylanHettinger please see my edits, you were missing `st_sfc`

Comment: That did it, thanks so much